# Got the error TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I am trying to build a register/login system with python and sqlite3. It seems to be there is something wrong here in my code.

```
        if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm"):
            return apology(" Passwords doesn't match")

#       try:

        prim_key = c.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
                                 username = request.form.get("username"),
                                 hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
        conn.commit()

#       except:
#           return apology("Sorry! username already exists!", 403)
#       if prim_key is None:
#           return apology("Failed to register! something went wrong!", 403)
#       user_if = prim_key
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

I commented some lines to figure out if what is wrong. Before quoting I kept getting the error "Sorry! username already exists!".

Now after quoting those lines when I run the application I get

> File "application.py", line 76, in register
> prim_key = c.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
> TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments

I wonder if I am missing, something these are the modules I imported.

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
import secrets
```

And if I can't use keyword arguments here, is there a way around this? Or am I doing the entire thing wrong? I am new to Python so I don't know if this is just a dumb question. I read almost all the questions like this one, but I couldn't figure any way to get this done. So any help is appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, `execute` doesn't take any keyword arguments. You need to just pass a dict of values instead:

```py
prim_key = c.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
                     { 'username': request.form.get("username"), 
                       'hash': generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
                     })
```